# Can't use Broadcom limited BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08) in 18.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I replaced the wireless card `intel 8265` to `DW1820a`, but I shield some stitch on this card.

### hardware info

run `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`

got this:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
```

### system info

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-66-generic
$ dmesg | grep brcm
[    5.755948] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd failed with error -2
[    5.755949] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd not found
```

#### Edit

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A 3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0022]
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba Corporation BG3 NVMe SSD Controller [1179:0113] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation Device [1179:0001]
```

And check the `bcmwl-kernel-source`

```
$ sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source
dpkg-query: package 'bcmwl-kernel-source' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

Then reboot:

```
$ dmesg | grep brcmf
[    4.419179] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.419214] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.524319] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin for chip 0x004350(17232) rev 0x000008
[    4.534207] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    6.972632] brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_query_dcmd: Timeout on response for query command
[    6.972637] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Retreiving cur_etheraddr failed, -5
[    6.972638] brcmfmac: brcmf_bus_started: failed: -5
[    6.972644] brcmfmac: brcmf_pcie_attach_bus: dongle is not responding
$ sudo updatedb && locate brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
```

### md5

```
$ ls -al /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 626140 3月  30  2017 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
$ md5sum /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
7ad59f4b16485a17a8e7cfcfb83906ab  /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A 3` in order to verify the driver in use for your wireless card ?

Comment: Please check: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source` If it is installed, remove it: `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Reboot and check again: `dmesg | grep brcmf` Also show us: `sudo updatedb && locate brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have edited the question.

Comment: May we also see: `ls -al /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin` and: `md5sum /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin` Thanks.

Comment: I try install .deb, the bluetooth work but it still not work. I get the .deb from http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248%2bbdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb. and use `sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*`